# Нижняя граница ряда таблицы (border-bottom) как картинка

Tags: html, css

Есть bootstrap-table:

[image]

При нажатии на нижнюю границу ряда выезжает подсказка. Хочу сделать эту границу в виде стрелочки вниз. Можно ли как-то сделать подобное? Пробовал border-image - не работает (хотя на других елементах div, textarea ..  работает нормально).

Пробовал:
Сss

```
    tr{
     border-image-slice: 0 0 22 0 !important;
     border-image-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px !important;
     border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
     border-image-repeat: stretch stretch !important;
     border-image-source: url("http://wordpress/wp-                                      content/uploads/2015/01/detailsDownSmall.png");
```

Comment: Вы папку расшарьте, что-ли, и ссылку нормальную дайте)

Comment: Ссылку исправил